# individual properties of my model in response asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I added comment for all properties of my model, but they are not displayed in the help page of web api 2.0. can someone please help me on this?

Here is a sample model from my app:

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the telephone.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The telephone.
    /// </value>
    public string telephone { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the mobile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The mobile.
    /// </value>
    public string mobile { get; set; }
}
```

In the help file generated the description column for telephone and mobile is empty. How can I add some description for that?

Comment: You'll need to provide some code, because we have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I made that comment, because your code wasn't displaying. You should update your question with that.

Comment: I updated my question with that. Thanks.

Comment: Is this model class in the same assembly as your Web API controllers?  The Help docs may be mis

Comment: Hi jandersen, the model class is in a different assembly, is there any way to include the description?

Answer (score 0):

you can add description and default value of property like following way :

```
[Description("Mobile Number")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
public string mobile { get; set; }
```

you can add its document by following way

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Name property </summary>
   /// <value>
   /// A value tag is used to describe the property value</value>
```

after adding it rebuild your project and check it in your xml document. if its display in your xml document then and then its display in api

Comment: Hi user3472361, i have tried this but still i don't see the description. I think the reason is because my model is in another assembly.

Comment: may be..have you check you xml document file?

Comment: It is not present in xml document file.

Comment: It is not present in xml document file thats why its not displaying in help api. if its display in xml document file then and then its display in help api. install nuget package in your other project where your class is added

Comment: which nuget package i need to install in other project?

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage .                    For more information refer this link : "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages"